# Prestashop Get combination product from id's

Tags: php, smarty, e-commerce, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to display quantity, combinations and etc. on the product-list. So far i've got it to display the combinations just fine, so that i can select an attribute from each group assigned to the product.

Now, how do i combine those "attribute id's" into a combination product, so that i can see prices, add it to cart etc.

This is my module to fetch combinations

```
function hookdisplayProductOnList($params){
    $product=new Product($params['id_product']);
    $combinations=$product->getAttributeCombinations($this->context->language->id);

    $combArray = [];
    $combArrayIds = [];

    foreach( $combinations as $k => $v )
    {   
        if( !in_array($v["id_attribute"], $combArrayIds))
        {
            $combArrayIds[] = $v["id_attribute"];
            $combArray[ $v["group_name"] ][] = $v;
        }
    }

    $this->smarty->assign('combinations',$combArray);
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'combinations.tpl');
}
```

This is how i output the groups

```
{foreach $combinations as $k=>$comb}

            <ul class="attribute-select" data-group="{$k}">
            {foreach from=$comb item=attr}
                <li data-combId="{$attr.id_attribute}" title="{l s='+'} {convertPrice price=$attr.unit_price_impact}">{$attr.attribute_name}</li>
            {/foreach}
            </ul><br />


{/foreach}
```

Is there any helper function or stuff like that. Like:

```
::GetByAttributes($product_id, [ attr_id1, attr_id2, attr_id3 ] );
```

Comment: maybe I misunderstood the task, but you already have `combinations` (other name "product_attribute" that contains just "attributes"), so customer can choose combination from list that you shows, and combination already have price  etc. I'm not sure what result you want to get from the helper function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a product ID and an array of attribute IDs you can get back a product attribute ID. I think that is what you need?

```
$productId = 123;
$attributeIds = [123, 1234];
$combinationId = (int) \Product::getIdProductAttributesByIdAttributes(
    $productId,
    $attributeIds
);
```

## Update

As noted in the comment by @PululuK in PrestaShop 1.7.3.1 this is deprecated and we should use `Product::getIdProductAttributeByIdAttributes()` instead, see https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/develop/classes/Product.php#L6511.

Comment: Whilst code only answers may provide a solution to the question, some form of explanation would help in making this a more useful answer.

Comment: This function is deprecated since ps 1.7.3.1  See https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/develop/classes/Product.php#L6511                                                     Nos you can use  ```getIdProductAttributeByIdAttributes```

Answer (score 1):

I used here id_product 21  , my prefix table is ps_ (default), the lang id is 1 , and the quantity is taken for the atributes stock

Here is the query i took from prestashop code , translated into a single query change it as you wish , it will give product attribute id , quantity and the prestashop format used for combinations

SELECT pac.id_product_attribute, 
(SELECT SUM(quantity) from ps_stock_available where id_product_attribute = pac.id_product_attribute) as quantity, GROUP_CONCAT(agl.`name`, '-',al.`name` ORDER BY agl.`id_attribute_group` SEPARATOR '-') as attribute_designation FROM `ps_product_attribute_combination` pac LEFT JOIN `ps_attribute` a ON a.`id_attribute` = pac.`id_attribute` LEFT JOIN `ps_attribute_group` ag ON ag.`id_attribute_group` = a.`id_attribute_group` LEFT JOIN `ps_attribute_lang` al ON (a.`id_attribute` = al.`id_attribute` AND al.`id_lang` = 1) LEFT JOIN `ps_attribute_group_lang` agl ON (ag.`id_attribute_group` = agl.`id_attribute_group` AND agl.`id_lang` = 1) WHERE pac.id_product_attribute IN (SELECT pa.id_product_attribute FROM ps_product_attribute pa WHERE pa.`id_product` = 21 GROUP BY pa.`id_product_attribute`) GROUP BY pac.id_product_attribute